# Iphone SQL Server Express data sync

Tags: iphone, sql-server-express

I have asked this question before but not for sql server express.
It seems that web services is not an option for syncing sql server express and iphone.

Besides that it is not a necessity to sync within 3G or a Wifi connection. It is good enough to connect the iphone to the pc so that it can find the sql server through the network (probably via bonjour services or something similar) and perform the calculations there.

I can build a .NET application that is responsible for it, but i would like to ask if i am on the correct path here, or if you have an easier solution to propose.

If the idea of using bonjour services is correct, then how should i get it sync properly with the iphone?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delayed answer!

Following a few requests elsewhere, I've put together a simple, generic, API for using SQL Server data in iOS apps. Whilst I've not explicitly tested against SQL Server Express yet, it should work exactly the same.

It's a small ASP.NET web service that runs on IIS, and a library you can add to your XCode project.

It's a beta at the moment, so I'd welcome any feedback, but there's [more info here](http://www.mobilefoo.com/iSqlServerSdk.html?utm_source=stack&utm_medium=weblink&utm_term=isql&utm_content=rcstackoverflow20110114&utm_campaign=isqlsdk)!

Cheers,
Rob